# Define a Component Value in DOM

Tags: angular, typescript, data-binding

I have a component that I want to alter each time a call it in the dom with its selector. This component will be a generic "Input Field" that has variables I want to define when I call it.

This is something I want to be scoped to the component when its called as I may call this component 5 times, each time with different values.

For example, my first call may have a label of "First Name", required, with a placeholder of "Enter your First Name".

### The component template:

```
<div class="input-group" *ngIf=visible>
  <span class="input-group-addon" *ngIf="required" id="basic-addon1">{{label}}<span *ngIf=required class="required"> *</span></span>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder={{placeholder}} aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
</div>
```

### Component.TS

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-input-field',
  templateUrl: './input-field.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./input-field.component.css']
})
export class InputFieldComponent implements OnInit {

visible:Boolean;
required:Boolean;
label:String;
disabled:Boolean;
placeholder:String;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

How do I define values to the component when I call its selector in the dom?

### DOM

```
<h1>
  Sample Input Fields
</h1>
<app-input-field [label]="First Name" [placeholder]="Enter first name" [required]=true visible=true></app-input-field>
```

^ What I have above doesn't work as they are not properties of the component.

### NOTE:

I do not know what the values will be and do not want to pass them from the parent container, I would like to only define these variables in the DOM.

Comment: `label`should be `@Input label`and so on - Read this https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **@Input** decorator on the fields you want to receive from the parent.

An example would be:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'input-component',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2> Hello {{name}} </h2>
    </div>
  `
})
export class InputComponent {
  @Input() name: string;
}
```

You can checkout a working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/c0GcSfgtJ3Hwkuwr0m7w?p=preview).